# Pytest and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've installed pytest 2.3.4 under Debian Linux.  By default it runs under Python 2.7, but sometimes I'd like to run it under Python 3.x, which is also installed.  I can't seem to find any instructions on how to do that.

The PyPI Trove classifiers show Python :: 3 so presumably it must be possible.  Aside from `py.test somedir/sometest.py`, I can use `python -m pytest ...`, or even `python2.7 -m pytest ...`, but if I try `python3 -m pytest ...` I get

`/usr/bin/python3: No module named pytest`

Comment: Even though this was asked over three years ago and I posted a workaround shortly thereafter, it seems people keep finding it and adding comments. For the record, Debian and pytest have moved on, so now with both `python-pytest` and `python3-pytest` installed, for a long time I have been running either `py.test` or `py.test-3` to choose from one or the other, so there's no need for the workaround either.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found a workaround:

1. Installed `python3-pip` using aptitude, which created `/usr/bin/pip-3.2`.
2. Next `pip-3.2 install pytest` which re-installed pytest, but under a python3.2 path.
3. Then I was able to use `python3 -m pytest somedir/sometest.py`.

Not as convenient as running py.test directly, but workable.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can replace the shebang line in py.test-3.x to point to your python3 interpreter. Worked for me.

Comment: You can auto-discover tests with just `python3 -m pytest` (without path), at least in 3.5.

Comment: To avoid this very conflict, `py.test` should _definitely_ install itself as either `py.test3` or `py3.test` when installed under Python 3. It doesn't. Arguably, this constitutes a bug. Until this is fixed, consider adding a fourth step to the above list for convenience: _4. Add the following `py.test3` shell alias to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` startup script:_ `alias py.test3='python3 -m pytest'` **Done.**

Comment: Goncalo, Mark, Cecil, thanks. I should point out that for quite some time now I have been using the Debian package `python3-pytest` which installs the script `py.test-3` (and also `py.test-3-5` under Python 3.5), so this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 28):

python3 doesn't have the module py.test installed.  If you can, install the `python3-pytest` package.

If you can't do that try this:

1. Install virtualenv
2. Create a virtualenv for python3

   - `virtualenv --python=python3 env_name`
3. Activate the virtualenv

   - `source ./env_name/bin/activate`
4. Install py.test

   - `pip install py.test`
5. Now using this virtualenv try to run your tests

Comment: In Debian (Wheezy), python3-pytest (and python-pytest) are at version 2.2.4, which is why I installed pytest 2.3.4 using pip. I'm also using tox, so I already have a py32 tox virtualenv.  However, sometimes it's convenient to invoke a test directly using python3 or python3.2 or python3.3.  Currently, all my tests are unittest, so I can easily invoke them with, e.g., `python3 -m unittest discover ...` or `python3.3 tests/sometest.py`, but it seems I won't be able to do something similar with pytest.

Comment: For reasons I am not familiar with, switching between virtual environments may require to refresh the PATH with `hash -r`.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
python3 $(which py.test) ...
```

Comment: Nice, this solved an issue I had with `six` (`six.PY3` was False), despite pytest installed in a virtual environment with python3.

Comment: In fact, the issue mentioned above was solved by `hash -r`. @Joe Abbate answer is the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the aforementioned `python3 -m pytest`, this might also work:

```
env pytest
```

Comment: This works for me, uses virtual env pytest I guess ?

Answer (score 4):

Install it with pip3:
`pip3 install -U pytest`

Comment: There are already 2 answers from 7 years ago that give basically the same answer. Please don't repeat existing answers.

Comment: Please excuse me, I don't see them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371623/466862 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371849/466862

Answer (score 1):

Debian Linux has the python3-pytest package where if installed you can simply run:

```
/usr/bin/pytest-3
```